# Low light illumination on ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling, light, voltage

I have a 15 yr old Hampton Bay ceiling fan with light fixture and remote.  Worked well when we bought home for a few years but suddenly the bulbs in the 3 bulb fixture are extremely dim. The bulbs have the small screw in base and are only 60w bulbs.. I removed the light fixture and tested the 2 wires (white and black) protruding down from the ceiling fan and it showed 48v.
I know very little about electricity and voltage.  The fan works fine.  Needing some professional advice please!

Comment: What type of lightbulbs are you using in the fixture? (incandescent, LED, CFL)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help (e.g. a picture of the inside of the wiring box). And, props for [taking our tour] before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 1):

There are voltage limiters in ceiling fans these are to prevent people from installing lamps that are a higher wattage than the fixture is listed for and overheating the fixture.

They were first mandated around 05 so this may be your issue.

It looks like a black square and has 2-3 wires as these fail they do get dimmer or go completely out.

I looked some up last week on amazon around 8$ for a replacement a 3 wire can replace a 2 wire but you have to connect the white to the neutral the 2wire is a direct replacement if you have a 2 wire but both are available the 3 wire last longer.